# Simple binary search in a vector

Tags: c++, binary-search

I was reading binary search from an interview book and changed some part of the algorithms.

It is working for all the values I tested with: i.e. all the values in array and outside the array extremes. I would appreciate another person's glance on my use of `lower <= upper` condition. Any other opinion is welcome, too.

```
std::pair<bool,size_t> BinarySearch(const std::vector<int>& array, int key) {

auto lower = array.begin();
auto upper = array.end()-1;
while (lower <= upper) {
    auto mid = lower + (upper-lower) /2;
    if(key == *mid)
    {
        return {true,std::distance(array.begin(),mid)};
    }
    if(key < *mid)
        upper = mid-1;
    else
        lower = mid+1;
}

return {false,std::distance(array.begin(),lower)};
}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

std::vector<int> arr {2,5,11,15};
auto result = BinarySearch(arr,5);
if(result.first)
    std::cout << result.second << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Not found " << std::endl;
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing I would change is the input type. If you look at the standard library you will find that containers and algorithms are connected via iterators. Thus allowing algorithms to be written for any container type that supports the appropriate iterators.

In your case; why only `std::vector`? This same algorithm should work for `std::array` and now you mention it `C-Arrays`. Which brings us to the return type. If you look at most `finding` type algorithms they will return an iterator to the element they found; if nothing is found then they return an element to `end()`.

There is no harm adding a wrapper that takes a container then calls the underlying code with `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

So first I would change your function to be just a wrapper.

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator BinarySearch(const std::vector<int>& array, int key)
{
    return BinarySearch(std::begin(array), std::end(array), key);
}
```

While we are talking about iterators and generalizing the code.The wrapper can be generalized to any container type (because nothing in the function is dependent on it being a `std::vector`) by simply adding a template.

```
template<tyepname C>
auto BinarySearch(C const& cont, int key)
{
    return BinarySearch(std::begin(cont), std::end(cont), key);
}
```

Range is from beginning to one past end generally.

```
auto lower = array.begin();
auto upper = array.end()-1;
```

You have taken the stance that your ranges are inclusive of end. As you will notice this actually makes your code harder when you have empty ranges. But also it makes your split inaccurate.

```
auto mid = lower + (upper-lower) /2;
```

To be correct that should have been:

```
auto mid = lower + ((upper-lower) + 1) /2;
```

I believe you will find that you slightly pesimizing searches for big numbers but slightly optimizing searches for small numbers.

The other things is if you have multiple values that match your key then you return a random one of these values. It might be more logical to return the first one? If you want to return a random one then you should definitely document that fact.

```
template<typename I>
I BinarySearch(I begin, I end)
{
    I lower = begin;
    I upper = end;
    while (lower < upper)
    {
        I mid = lower + std::distance(upper, lower) / 2;
        if(key == *mid)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if(key < *mid) {
            upper = mid;
        }
        else {
            lower = mid;
        }
    }

    return end;
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from 2log(N) comparisons instead of log(N)+1 many. I know of interviewers who reject this solution.

Comment: @Maikel: Well that just goes to show there are bad interviewers out there. If they reject a perfectly good candidates their loss because I'll hire somebody with this solution. The thing to note in an interview is `The other things is if you have multiple values that match your key then you return a random one of these values.`  I agree that it could be optimized. But I prefer to go with readability first then optimize if required later.

Comment: @Maikel: O(log(n)) is the same as O(2.log(n)) in complexity.

Comment: Thats why omitted big-O notation and talk about its constants. I just think that algorithmic deficits are more important tham stylistic ones.

Comment: Your solution also does not return a random equivalent element. That would require looking for lower and upper bounds of equivalent elements and a rng. Its all not too important anyway. I just wanted to note that the solution lacks something algorithmically.

Comment: @Maikel: Unless you are doing Big Data problems then this is a perfectly valid solution. If you are doing Big Data problems then its not even close; but then again your solution also falls way short of a correct implementation for Big Data. So tamato/tomato. So I really don't see any algorithmic deficits. It is fine for the scale of problem we want to solve.

Comment: If we want to talk about algorithmic deficiencies lets talk best worst an average. The above `O(1)/O(log(n))/O(log(n))` yours `O(log(n))/O(log(n))/O(log(n))` so you are loosing out on all those best case situations where the above is `O(1)` where it hits the test on the first element.

Comment: @Maikel: Its not an advantage to hit a random element. That's a deficiency in my algorithm. Yours finds the lowest bound a much more useful piece of information usually.

Comment: @Maikel: Lets think about the actual overhead here of actually making twice as many comparisons. Say some medium sized piece of data with 100 million integers. log2(100,000,000) is 26.5 (lets call that 27). So searching 100,000,000 integers I have to test an integer 27 more time on 4 GHz processors. I don't think you have saved any time. If your searching a bigger data set then the comparison operation is not your concern its managing the data and how it gets into memory.

Comment: If they scale about the same in the number of items, I would suggest to look into the case of expensive comparisons, where constants matter a lot. For *example*, if you are not looking for `int`s but for `std::string`s. Its a possible use case for an algorithm like binary search. If an interviewer is interested in designing generic algorithms this might make a difference (and in fact made one for me as a failing candidate).

Comment: @Maikel: Again I disagree. This totally depends on your use case. Sure if you have gigabyte strings that extra comparison may come back and byte you. But you don't build structures for the worst case you build them for the normal case. You don't pessimise your normal use case just because there is a potential for a stupid person to abuse your structure. Then if they don't perform you special case them.

Answer (score 7):

- Your code fails if you pass an empty vector because in this case `array.end()-1` is incorrect
- Keep const correctness, `key` should be `const` too
- You have kind of strange code formatting, you should rather create an indent after every opening bracket, and not keep function body on a same level
- Consider imitating STL approach and returning iterator instead of `std::pair`
- You limit yourself to `std::vector<int>` type. Read about templates and try to make code that accept different types as well, for example `std::vector<double>`.
- Calling `std::vector` an array is confusing, note that there's also `std::array` in C++11 and C-style arrays. `vec` would be better name there.
- Size of `std::vector<int>` is not actually `std::size_t` but `std::vector<int>::size_type`

Comment: Using `const` on input parameters (i.e. on `key`), which are given by value is at least debatable.

Comment: @Maikel I just don't think changing key to be searched from within search function shoud be allowed, so why not make compiler enforce this.

Comment: In general, if I define an interface all I care is that `key` is not getting modified on the outside, but I do not care what the actual implementation does with it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Nykalin I want to add an algorithmic nitpick.

Your equality test

```
if(key == *mid)
```

is an additional comparison in each step. Imagine your are not looking for `int`s but in a vector of large `std::string`s. Just make an `upper_bound`-like search and test this bound. Schematically:

```
template <typename I, typename T>
I binary_search(I first, I last, const T& value)
{
  I ub = upper_bound(first, last, value);
  assert(!(*ub < value));
  // Equality means: !(*ub < value) && !(value < *ub)
  if (ub != last && !(value < *ub)) {
    return ub;
  }
  return last;
}
```

You will see that implementing `upper_bound` is very simple and beautiful in comparison to a direct `binary_search`.

Edit:

What I call here "upper_bound"-like search is implemented in the STL as `std::lower_bound` not to confuse with `std::upper_bound`.